# Qt4: Print a SQL table to PDF

Tags: sql, qt, pdf, printing, database-table

Qt has built-in PDF export support (`QPrinter::PdfFormat`).

What's the best way to print an SQL table to a PDF file? (a table from a database loaded with `QSqlDatabase` and linked to a `QTableView`)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use QWidget::render. See the documentation about [Printing Widgets](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/printing.html#printing-widgets).

Comment: tried it - gives bitmapped results (only an image of the widget) - text would be better

Comment: That's surprising. But if you think about it and read the documentation carefully, you can expect it. I tried printing to pdf with the richtext/orderform example, and the printing of a QTextEdit produces a pdf file with text. My conclusion: Write your table to a QTextDocument and call its print method.

Comment: Re writing to QTextDocument: You have to generate HTML with a table and use QTextDocument::setHtml.

Comment: If you want your pdf to containt text, you can try this one https://github.com/T0ny0/Qt-Table-Printer